# When Ubuntu asks for credentials, how do I know it is Ubuntu and not malware with a phishing attack?

Tags: security, malware

Ubuntu frequently asks for credentials when downloading updates. What is to stop malware from just producing a pop-up that mimics the same behaviour?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87288/70524

Answer (score 3):

Nothing stops a program from creating a dialog that asks for your password. It's your responsibility as a user to only enter your password into trusted programs. However, all of this assumes an attacker cares about becoming root, which it may not care about.

For the most part an attacker can do most everything they want without becoming root in the assumption you will login to the same user again at a later time. If they want to fire up their botnet or start encrypting your files they can do that without being a super-user.

The most effective tool in Linux that stops malware is the trusted repository and package signature system. In Windows you typically download .exe files from arbitrary websites, at any layer they can be infected from hosting to transmit etc. In Linux most software is found from the central repository of software which has been signed by the Ubuntu team. If the package is modified the signature will not match and the infected package will not run.

Overall if you only install software from trusted sources and never run random binaries you find from the web you will have a secure system. Linux just provides the user tools to accomplish this better.

Comment: >It's your responsibility as a user to only enter your password into trusted programs. How do I know which program launches the request?

Comment: Whichever program you clicked on. For example, if you download a random Linux binary from some server you have to first give it executable rights and then open it. Most honest programs are written in a way to show an error if the libraries they need are not installed, they don't typically ask to become root to automatically install packages, and if they do they typically open the system's choice of terminal and show the command that will be ran.

Comment: Contrast that to a package that is installed from the trusted repository that may ask to become root such as `gnome-system-monitor` when you attempt to change the priority of a running process.

Comment: Also likewise if a program is supposed to be ran as root and is not it usually spits out "run me as root" and then exits, and it's the users responsibility to become root somehow (like using `sudo`) and then run that program.

Comment: Could an attacker conceivably not create a popup to 'install updates' that looks identical to the one Ubuntu provides, and when I click to go ahead, ask for credentials? Is that far-fetched paranoia or reasonable paranoia?

Comment: You have to think of "entry points" and how you get software like that onto a system. For example, in Ubuntu where you are getting your programs and what icons are you clicking on to run programs? The goal is to make it so users NEVER enter authenticate or enter their password into any untrusted applications. This is why you use the Software Center to install signed packages or the Control Center. Many programs don't ask to become a super user and users shouldn't be allowing random binaries on their system let alone giving them super user capabilities without understanding the program.

Comment: Consensus seems to be simply: only install software from the software center and you don't have to worry about it

Comment: Yes all software should be installed through the package manager. Take a look at how Steam does it in an honest way, they need users to install packages for their 3D drivers but they don't want to ask for a password etc. so they launch a terminal with a sudo command you must allow.

Comment: so as long as I don't mess with the standard repositories, I can run sudo apt-get install and it will only install software from the trusted repos? Am I understanding how this is set up correctly?

Comment: That is correct. Any packages grabbed by `apt-get` are pulled from your repository list, which by default includes only packages signed by Ubuntu amd Debian maintainers.

Comment: "Overall if you only install software from trusted sources and never run random binaries you find from the web you will have a secure system"  Well, a MORE secure system.  You're still at risk from mistake (ie Heartbleed) plus hidden nasties which haven't been spotted yet (because it's a hard problem to solve).